# Impossible to display full screen Flash content on iMac 5k?

Tags: imac, adobe-flash

It seems to be a problem that at least [two other persons](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6664274) are facing.

When I watch a video it works fine, but if I switch to full screen, the area where Flash should be rendered is totally black.

The right click is showing me the Flash options which means that the plug-in does not crash, just it does not display anything.

Could anyone solve this issue or should we just wait for some Flash update?

Comment: Did you try it with & without hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "fix" this by disabling the build in chrome pepper flash and enabling the flash player plugin (download flash from adobe first)

Type chrome://plugins/ in your address bar

[image]

I had the same issue with my mbpr when it was just released with chrome. Have to wait for a pepperflash update. With the mbpr it took a while.